# Limit number of results after query population in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose query in which i limit the number of results to lets say 3 entries. My problem is, that every object gets populated with nested objects. This nested objects have an "active"-flag. I do not want to return any object which have a nested object where the "active"-flag is false, but the population filter is applied after the limit and therefore the result could be empty.

Is it possible to do something like this without executing the query once again with another offset until the limit is reached?

Example:

```
Activity.find(query)
        .skip(offset)
        .limit(limit)
        .sort({timestamp: -1})
        .populate('source')
        .exec()
```

The offset and limit is for an endless scrolling functionallity.

What i have tried is this:

```
Activity.find(query)
        .skip(offset)
        .populate('source').
        .where('source.active').equals(true)
        .limit(limit)
        .sort({timestamp: -1})
        .exec()
```

Comment: You can filter the object after getting result using either lodash function or JavaScript function.

Comment: By populated with nested object, do you mean referenced objects are being populate using `populate` function in your case? Giving query example would be help us in understanding scenario better.

Comment: Hi Tobias; can you [edit] your question to show your query? It would be easier to know how to amend it, if we know what you're starting with.

Comment: Sure. I added it

Comment: @TobiasStangl I am facing the same situation now. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Qiulang Hi, yes. I posted an answer to the the problem.

Comment: Hi, I am still trying to figure out my aggregate clauses, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the problem is to use the aggregation framework of mongoose (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

Afterwards, the code looks as follows (simplified):

```js
Activity.
  .aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'source',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'user_docs'
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        user_docs: {
          $elemMatch: {
            active: true
          }
        }
    },
    {$limit: options.limit},
    {$sort: {timestamp: -1}}
    ]);
```

An additional population can be done afterwards via Model.populate(results, path).

Answer (score 0):

You can populate multiple documents specifu:
You can populate multiple documents by specifying the `path`, `match` where you can select the active ones and also you can use the `options`:

```
Activity
  .find(query)
  .skip(offset)
  .populate({
    path: 'source',
    match: {
      active: true
    }
  })
  .limit(limit)
  .sort({
    timestamp: -1
  })
  .exec()
```

For more check the documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Thanks, but that's actually not possible, because the nested object have to be populated first.